psutil can't detect chrome processes from inside python script
The following script is fine for windows but for Ubuntu, it only works on Python shell when I ran the code inside my script it did not detect chrome processes. Your help will be appreciated.
Here is my code:
def kill_processes():
    print('Process killing started...')
    proc_list = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if "chrome" in proc.name().lower() or "uc_driver" in proc.name().lower():
            proc_list.append(proc)
            proc.terminate()
            print(proc)
            time.sleep(1)  # Adjust timing as needed
            if proc.is_running():
                proc.kill()
    gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(
        proc_list, timeout=3)  # Adjust timing as needed
    for proc in alive:
        proc.kill()


I'm having trouble parsing the part of the sentence after "it only works". Could you clarify when it works and when it doesn't?

When it doesn't detect chrome processes, does the ps command in the shell show them?

I don't see any obvioius problem with the script logic. If it's not detecting any chrome processes, it means psutil can't find them.

Try adding print(proc.name()) to the loop and see if you can detect a pattern to the difference from ps.

Do you run the script in a virtual environment?

I added print to check I tried everything. It works fine outside of my python script. I also write a shell script to run it but it doesn't work. Yes, I am using virtual environment. But if the issue is virtual environment then it also should not work outside script because even outside script I have venv activated. For windows it work fine.
I am in AWS ec2 environment with Ubuntu AMI
Surprisingly, if I remove the if statement for chrome it shows other processes.

The print statement shows other processes that aren't in the venv? It shows everything except chrome?

Why would chrome be running in an EC2 instance? Isn't it a headless server? Are you running Selenium Chromedriver?

Yes, it shows other processes I don't know much about them like some of them start with the name kernel. I am building a scraping bot in Seleniumbase and running Chrome in headless mode.

When I ran the code on Ubuntu it just shows:
Process killing started...
Process killing ends...
That's it but the same code kills processes on windows and also print them on console.
